# Detect the specific hash in URL

Tags: javascript

So i have a website where i would like to create a navigation based on URL's hash.
My goal is to achive it without AJAX and only change the display settings based on the specific hash.
Is there any way to do it with `if`?
If i was expeienced i would probably laugh at myself but i tried something like this:

Let's say my URL is something.com/file.html#home

```js
function someFunction () {
 var hash = window.location.hash;
 if (hash == home) {
     //Changing some settings based on the hash
 }
}
```

I would be grateful for help.

Comment: `if (hash == 'home') {`.... you have `home` as a variable, and `=` _assigns_, where `==` compares....

Comment: Be mindful that a single `=` assigns the value to a variable. Two or more `==` / `===` compares two values.

Comment: This would be very bad for users who have JavaScript disabled or people using text-mode browsers, like text-mode screen-readers for the blind. Please don't do this.

Comment: To be fair, the internet is very bad if you have javascript disabled!

Comment: I know about double = symbol but i just forgot to write it here,

Comment: I'm not worried about people who disabled javascript because it's almost impossible to browse without it nowdays...

Comment: @Dai, a huge percentage of websites rely on JavaScript to function nowadays. Even Google have just this past day made it a requirement to login to their apps. People without JavaScript enabled should not stand in the way of progress.

Comment: Guys please, I'm happy to talk with you but my script is still... quite not working...

Comment: @FalsePride I really don't know what you're asking. You have the basic structure there - we can't fill in the details because we don't know what your requirements are. But it's not hard to do "if the hash is X then do these actions, or if it's Y then do these instead, otherwise...". You just put the relevant `if/else` statements in and the right code for your use-case inside each.

Comment: Use `indexOf()` to see if a particular string is WITHIN the hash string - e.g. `if (hash.indexOf('mysubstring') > 0) { //do summat }` *(assuming you keep using `hash` as your variable name)*

Comment: The unsolved problem here is how to deal with URLencoding; e.g. `if (location.hash == '#'+id)` isn't quite right if e.g. `id == "HQ9+"`, because you'll find that `location.hash == "#HQ9%2B"` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.hash` contains the `#` symbol. You can either include it on your comparison, or remove it from the variable hash.

Include the hash symbol:

```
if (hash === "#home")
```

Or remove the hash symbol:

```
var hash = "home"; // default 
if (window.location.hash.length > 0) {
    hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I know I'm breaking some Stackoverflow rules by this comment but just thank you. I've started learning web design in hope of getting to advanced javascript.... And because I'm an artist...

Comment: The '`#`' character is simply called the "hash symbol", **not "hashtag"** - that's a neologism referring to the `#` symbol used as part of a tagging system of taxonomy.

Comment: @Dai I hesitated for a moment on what to call it, but I figured hashtag is the friendliest term for new programmers.

Comment: @Ibu I understand, but if beginners search online for "how to use hashtag" they'll get very different results :) Thank you for editing your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf() to see if a particular string is WITHIN the hash string - e.g.

```
if (hash.indexOf('mysubstring') > 0) { //do summat }
else if (hash.indexOf('nuther substring') > 0) { //do summat else }
```

*(assuming you keep using hash as your variable name)*